# Producers sending protobuf and json messages. Need a way to differentiate among them

Tags: json, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

Kafka producer is sending protobuf and json messages. Is there a way to identify if a message is of the form protobuf or json and then process it accordingly?

Comment: Looks like a poor design if same topic can contains that different types of messages. However, you can mark messages with a custom header and process them in a different way according to its value.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the producer is doing this. Is it just repeating the same message, first as GPB binary wireformat, then as GPB's JSON representation? Or is the JSON conveying a completely different type of object? If it's the same object, one could have an initial guess based on message length; the JSON form of a message is going to be longer than the GPB binary form. Having used length to guess, you'd still have to try-catch in case the guess was wrong. But the length check first could mean getting it right more often, saving a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your consumer with ByteArrayDeserializer.

Put a try-catch in your poll loop and deserialize one or the other... I'd recommend trying Protobuf first since I'd expect its binary format to be more easily detected than JSON.

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to convince your producers to add extra metadata that you can parse